# React TypeScript: Save array of strings to state and display array in unordered list

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to save an array to state and then I want to somehow loop over the array that was saved to state in the dom to create an unordered list using one item from the array for each

The array values in the example below are just to make it simple, they actually come from a database and I don't know the values ahead of time, but I do know they are strings.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const Worbli: React.FC = () => {

  const [state, setState] = useState({
     myArray = '';
  });
  const theArrayToSave = ['apple', 'orange', 'peach'] 
  setState({ ...state, myArray: theArrayToSave });

  return (
    <ul>
      { state.myArray.map( (fruit:string,index:number) => (<li key={index} >{fruit}</li>)) }
    </ul>
  )
}
```

The error I get is

```
Argument of type '{ myArray: string[]; accountNameError: string; loading: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ accountNameError: string; loading: boolean; myArray: string; }>'.
  Type '{ myArray: string[]; }' is not assignable to type '{ myArray: string; }'.
    Types of property 'myArray' are incompatible.
      Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the initial value be an array? `myArray = [];`

Comment: It's still incompatible Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.

Comment: It seems like you are missing a lot of typings in your code, did you exclude them for the code sample purpose or you didn't add them?

Comment: @Cristy I was just trying to simplify the code so it was easy to look at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare your state like this:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
  myArray: [];
});
```

But as you mentioned before, this makes it a `never[]` type instead of a `string[]` type and still throws an error. To solve this you should add types to your state declaration like this:

```
interface IState {
  accountNameError: string;
  loading: boolean;
  myArray: string[];
}

const [state, setState] = useState<IState>({
  accountNameError: "",
  loading: false,
  myArray: []
});
```

This way you specifically tell `TypeScript` what your state value should look like.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize your state with an empty array instead of initializing it with a an empty string. It should work

```
const [state, setState] = useState<{myArray:string[]}>({
     myArray: [];
  });
```

Comment: It's still incompatible Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'

Comment: I corrected, now it should works because useState like some others React hooks use [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), so you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

First declare your `useState` type and set your default array like this:

live preview example: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-river-p3cfl

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

type IState = {
  myArray: string[];
};

const Worbli: React.FC = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<IState>({
   myArray: ["apple", "orange", "peach"]
  });

  return (
    <ul>
      {state.myArray.map((fruit: string, index: number) => (
        <li key={index}>{fruit}</li>
      ))}
     <button
       onClick={() =>
       setState({ myArray: [...state.myArray, "Random Fruit Name?"] })
     }
    >
      Add to state
  </button>
</ul>
);
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<Worbli />, rootElement);
```